# Uncaught ReferenceError: $alertable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-plugins

I have used `jquery.alertable` plugin to my site but its not working in my pages. i got some errors saying

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $alertable is not defined'

so please help me to solve this problem. thank yo in advance

this is my error from chrome

[image]

Comment: did you add jQuery library before your alterable library?

Comment: yes i have added all the needed libraries

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation:
https://github.com/claviska/jquery-alertable

```
$.alertable.prompt('How many?').then(function(data) {
  // Prompt was submitted
});
```

So instead of using $alertable use $.alertable

Comment: Not even checking the documentation, the screenshot he shows has the correct example above it...

Comment: i have done the changes , but still i am getting the same error